# ios - implementing interface for right handed and for left handed

Tags: ios, ios8, uistoryboard

In my app i need separate UI for left-handed users and for right-handed users. The difference is basically that the buttons are on the right side of the screen or the left side of the screen.

What is the way to build the UI to support this kind of requirement? How should i specify auto-layout constraints to allow that?

Comment: You could look into how it's done for Right-to-Left languages, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html

Comment: How do you know which hand is being used? I'm left handed but I use my iPhone in my right hand half of the time.

Comment: I will ask the user which he prefers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have two choices:

- You could design the entire interface twice, in pairs of scenes or even two storyboards, and load the appropriate view controller scene or storyboard depending on the user's preference.
- You could prepare your code to swap constraints in and out (or change their `constant` values) in real time when the user changes preference.